# Kifflom! missions not appearing after epsilon program survey

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, xbox-one

I've filled out the epsilon program survey multiple times via the website and have waited in-game weeks for the first Kifflom! mission to appear and still nothing.

Is this expected? How long can it take for the first mission to appear on the map?

Answer (score 1):

When I first completed it, same thing happened. Then I played and played, got around %70, and then I filled it again, and it was **instantly** there.

Note: Some sources state that it can be done anytime after unlocking Micheal.

There are [a few](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200431633-epsilon-program-not-progressing) issues that report this, some fixes include:

- I went to GTAO, then I left from pause menu and back to single player there was the Epsilon symbol on the map [by Lorenzo23_ITALY]
- Save the game, load it and try it again [by me, ardaozkal]

Comment: Ok thanks ardaozal I'm on 84% so still have stuff to do. I'll keep playing and see what happens. I was hoping to kick this mission off sooner because of the delays in between missions, but will have to be patient!